# CSS Div overlaps text

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlapping

I'm releasing a new feature on my website and I want to mark the new a-tag in the navbar with a "NEW" sign top right of the a-tag (little overlapping). But I don't know how to make this overlapping happen and that my span with "NEW" (the text) is shown in full-width. Difficult to describe for me, current status is in the picture. I tried z-index, didn't work.
Here is my code.

navbar html and css:

```
<li class="nav-item p-1">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="overview/cases" routerLinkActive="active-link" (click)="collapsed=true">Cases<span class="new-feature">NEW</span></a>
    </li>
    
    .new-feature{
      width: 50px;
      height: 20px;
     background: linear-gradient(135deg, #9932cc, #fa490a);
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 15px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

It currently looks like this:

[image: current status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try give relative position to `<a>` or `<li>` and absolute position to `<span>`, than z-index will be working

```
   <li class="nav-item p-1" style="position:relative;">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="overview/cases" routerLinkActive="active-link" (click)="collapsed=true">Cases
     <span class="new-feature" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">NEW</span>
    </a>
   </li>
```

Comment: okay thank a lot! i did the positioning and then adjusted top and left.

Answer (score 0):

Give `position:absolute` to `.new-feature` and `position:relative` to its parent class. You can play with values to fit to your need.

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.nav-item{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.new-feature-wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
.new-feature{
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 10px;
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, #9932cc, #fa490a);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item p-1 new-feature-wrapper">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="overview/cases" routerLinkActive="active-link" (click)="collapsed=true">Cases<span class="new-feature">NEW</span></a>
        </li>
```